# SQL Server errors deleting date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-delete

Using SQL Server 2012, trying to delete the contents of a table. I am getting the "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.".

There is a nvarchar(Max) column that may contain Date or DateTime values for some rows. These rows I suspect are the ones causing this error. Researched a bit but haven't found a solution. I would understand this error if I am trying to update certain values, or inserting data, but not on a Delete. This is my query.

```
Delete From [dbo].[Field]
```

This is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Field](
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[FormID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Key] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
[Value] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Field] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Is there any trigger that fires on delete?

Comment: You have no `Where` clause. Why not just `Truncate` the table?

Answer (score 1):

The pure `delete` command will not give you such error message, I think there is some other constraint that you have in the target table such as DML triggers that will fire after the `delete` command, it looks like it was trying to insert a string to a column which is `date` or `datetime` or `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset`. Make sure the string is written in correct format, or you could disable the trigger and try to delete the records again.

**What you were trying to do has a great potential of data loss because you did not specify the certain condition using `where`, and I assume the query option is set default to `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` OFF, which will automatically commit the `delete` command.**

Back to your question, you could try to check `SET STATISTICS IO` ON, and try to using `BEGIN TRAN tran1 delete from [dbo].[Field]`, the result message will be little bit more informative. After figuring out whether or not it is the DML trigger prevent you from deleting, then finally do `COMMIT TRAN tran1`

Comment: There are no triggers. There are views that depend on the table, and some indexes on the views to speed up reading data. The delete needs to wipe out all of the data prior to updating the table with data from another database. I suspect that I may need to drop all indexes on the views that use this table to make the Delete work. My question still is, why does this happen? Doesn't make sense to me even if there are indexes on related views.

Comment: If the table is one member of the view, I am guessing the view was created with `WITH SCHEMABINDING` option which will prevent you from modifying any data change in the underlying tables before you drop the view.

Comment: If Schemabinding is the issue, then, do I need to remove all indexes from related Views? This seems like a bug, as this shouldn't prevent me from deleting data. I would understand if I am trying to modify the data types, drop columns, etc., but deleting data when there are not parent/child relation ship constraints (which do enforce SQL rules to avoid deleting/updating data related to another table) should not provoke this.

Comment: hmm, you are right, it won't affect the data rows.I think probably it is related to the index on that view.

Comment: I altered all views and removed the Schemabinding option. I still think that this is a bug as removing data in no way changes the relationship between the views and the underlying table. If anyone can provide an explanation on to why this is necessary then I would appreciate it (always good to learn).

Comment: 1.could you right click the table, `View dependencies` and to check.  2.try to `SET STATISTICS IO` to ON and execute the query again, and check the result message. 3.try to run the following using that database: select b.name,a.name From sys.triggers as a inner join sys.tables as b on b.object_id = a.parent_id, to see any other triggers depend on the others depend on that table

Comment: pay attention to those triggers if it has (lightening symbol)

Comment: can you add the DDL for the views?

Comment: There are no triggers whatsoever, I know, I created the database and been working with it for the last 2 months. The issue simply was the schemabinding on the indexes created on the views that use the table.